# display list[0] list[1] in template form default value

Tags: django

I have a tag list passed to template

```
context = {"tags": ["python", 'django']}
```

I want to retrieve them respectively as the input default value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" 
placeholder="Search ..." value="[{{ tags[0] }}] [{{ tags[1] }}]">
```

I intend it to be displayed as

```
[python] [django]
```

in the search bar but I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the following syntax:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" 
       placeholder="Search ..." value="[{{ tags.0 }}] [{{ tags.1 }}]">
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups:

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable name signifies a **lookup**. Specifically, when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup. Example: **foo["bar"]**
> - Attribute lookup. Example: **foo.bar**
> - List-index lookup. Example: **foo[bar]**